How to avoid infinite loop in a VBA macro on Word when adding new paragraphs
I am trying to create a VBA macro in Word that checks if a paragraph text consists of dots. If true, I want to add more dots until the whole line is filled with dots. The problem I am facing is that my macro enters an infinite loop.
I have the following code:
Sub Dots()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    Dim paragraph As paragraph
    For Each paragraph In doc.Paragraphs
        If Left(paragraph.Range.Text, 6) = "......" Then
            If Right(paragraph.Range.Text, 5) = "(NR)" & vbCr Then
                paragraph.Range.Text = String(112, ".") & " (NR)" & vbCr
            ElseIf Right(paragraph.Range.Text, 4) = "..." & vbCr Then
                paragraph.Range.Text = String(122, ".") & vbCr
            End If
        End If
    Next paragraph
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I suppose the problem is that, after changing the paragraph text with a vbCr in the end, the next loop analysis the same paragraph again. But if I don't add a vbCr, the paragraph will be merged with the next one.
Any ideas, please?

Use a For loop and loop backwards:
Dim i As Long
For i = doc.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
    Dim paragraph As paragraph
    Set paragraph = doc.Paragraphs(i)

    If Left(paragraph.Range.Text, 6) = "......" Then
    ' rest of your code

Next


Dim paragraph As paragraph should be outside the loop.

@TimothyRylatt Dim statements aren't executed in a loop. It doesn't matter whether it's inside or outside the loop, just as long as it precedes variable usage.

Thanks. Never came across that before. 30 years writing VBA and I'm still learning.
